# How can I only return only the last 10 fields based on date to a view?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In this project there are two sql tables. The first table is Cars and the second is Mobiles.  These two tables each have an ExpirationDate field.  I want to show the last 10 fields from these two tables based on expiration date in one view.

```
public ActionResult Index(int ?page)
{
      var result = db.Mercedes.Where(m => m.Username == User.Identity.Name).OrderByDescending(m=>m.CurrentDate);
      var result2 = db.Mobiles.Where(m => m.UserName == User.Identity.Name).OrderByDescending(m => m.CurrentDate);
      int pageSize = 6;
      int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

      return View(result.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));              
}
```

Comment: Do they share a base class?

Comment: Have a look at [linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx).

Comment: @Cort3z Don't you see the LINQ in the code?

Comment: You should look into [Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx)

Comment: Normal SQL could also help: "Select TOP 10 from Mercedes orderby CurrentDate descending"

Answer (score 1):

What you'll need to do is refactor those two queries to return the same class.

You then combine the two IQueryable sets and perform your Take(10) on the third, combined resultset.

example:

```
var result = from m in db.Mercedes 
             where m.Username == User.Identity.Name  
             orderby m.CurrentDate descending 
             select new car(){param1 = m.param1/*etc*/};
var result2 = from m in db.Mobiles 
              where m.Username == User.Identity.Name  
              orderby m.CurrentDate descending 
              select new car(){param1 = m.param1/*etc*/};
var combinelist = result.Concat(result2)
.OrderByDescending(m=>m.CurrentDate)
.Take(10)
.ToList();
```

Comment: This is essentially the same thing that Abi Ruban has shown. Although he doesn't take into account the two different classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LINQ [Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) and [ToList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) methods:

```
        var result = db.Mercedes.Where(m => m.Username == User.Identity.Name).OrderByDescending(m=>m.CurrentDate);
        var result2 = db.Mobiles.Where(m => m.UserName == User.Identity.Name).OrderByDescending(m => m.CurrentDate);

        var combinelist= result.Concat(result2).ToList();
```

Comment: You are going to get a compile-time exception because you can't concatenate a List<Mercedes> and a List<Mobile>.